# How to Copy and Insert Table Row using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with the following structure

```
<table id='table1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='rowa'>
          <td><select>....</select></td>
        <tr>
        ...
        <tr id='rowx'>
          <td>....</td>
        </tr>
        ...
        <tr id='rowz'>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is on clicking of a button, I want to copy the rowa and insert it before rowx.

What I am currently doing is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function copyRow() {
        var row = $('#rowa').clone();
        $('#rowx').before(row);
    }
</script>
```

It seems to show the newly constructed row before the rowx but when I try to access that new row, it does not work. what I mean by does not work in that the select input item does not behave like a select item, it behaves like the static text.

elsewhere on the page I have

```
<a href='javascript:copyRow()'><img src='images/copyrow.png' title='Copy Row' /></a>
```

Sorry! I should have made it clear that the copyRow is being called when the user clicks on a link somewhere else on the page.

Comment: please post the select tag as well :)

Comment: Have a look at jsfiddle.net where you can showcase your issue completely

Comment: @mplungjan -- JSFiddle is down right now :\ -- using JSBIN as a workaround.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsbin.com/uxumal/1/edit

Comment: What do you mean with "select input item behaves like the static text" ?

Comment: It means it behaves like an image for the combo box, so you cant click on the combo box to see the drop down options, it just shows as an image, which is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsbin.com/owivin/1/.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rowx").before($("#rowa").clone());
});
```

Your code's not working because you never call `copyRow()`. I put it in the `document.ready()` so that it would run as the document gets ready!

Comment: I edited my post to show that onclick handler, this needs to be done when the user clicks the image.